# How Can I Fix a Fraying Earbud Cable?

Tags: audio, cables, headphones

My KZ earbud is broken, I don't hear anything from the left speaker. After a quick inspection I noticed the cable is fraying. The cable is detachable but I don't want to buy a new one.

Do you think I can fix it? If so, please let me know how.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enerally, You can not reliably fix it unless you cut and re-solder it to its original location.

Bad news, this looks like overmolded connector so if you will try to break it open, you probably won't salvage anything. This is not meant to be repaired.